# Regex troubles (probally) on return carriage and new line

Tags: java, regex

I have the following text:

```
&rule_c(2-7, <<'EOF');
cout << "Hello World.\n";
return x;
EOF
```

I want to match this text into a regular expression.

The one I was thinking about was:

```
^&rule_c\((\d+)\-(\d+),\s?\<\<\s?\'EOF\'\);\r?\n|\r\n?(.*\r?\n|\r\n?)+EOF\r?\n|\r\n?$
```

I tried it with Java:

```
private static final String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator").toString();
 ...
String textual = "&rule_c(2-7, <<'EOF');" + newLine
 + "cout << "Hello World.\n";" + newLine
 + "return x;" + newLine
 + "EOF" + newLine;

String lineSep = "\\r?\\n|\\r\\n?";
String regex = "^&rule_c\\((\\d+)\\-(\\d+),\\s?\\<\\<\\s?\\'EOF\\'\\);"
  + lineSep + "(.*" + lineSep + ")+EOF" + lineSep + "$";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(textual);
if (m.matches()) {
    rangeLowerBound = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
    rangeUpperBound = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));


    String[] tmp = m.group(3).split(lineSep);
    System.out.println(tmp.toString());
    for (String l : tmp)
        System.out.println(l);

    lineSet = new ArrayList<String>();
    Collections.addAll(lineSet, tmp);

} else
    System.out.println("regex doesn't match!");
 ...
```

The only result i'm obtaining is `regex doesn't match!`.

Where I'm failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `String lineSep = (?:\\r?\\n|\\r\\n?)+;` (and not `String lineSep = [\\r?\\n|\\r\\n?]+;` that actually matches `|` and `?` characters, too) to solve, combining answers and suggestions from **Pshemo** (mainly) and **Fedor Skrynnikov**.

Also 'used suggestion from **Bohemian** to remove unnecessary character escaping.

[Here](http://regexr.com?36mb1) there is the example from [gskinner.com](http://gskinner.com)'s RegEx Tester.

Comment: If you use `[\\r?\\n|\\r\\n?]` it will match `\r` `\n` `|` and `?` characters. If you want to use character class then you probably should write it as `"[\r\n]+"` (there is no need to duplicate `\n` and `\r` but this will also match many empty lines like `\r\n\r\n` and so on.

Comment: `|` and `?` are not escaped.
I need to match (at least) a new line sequence in diffrent Operative Systems. _*nix like_ new line char is `\n` (left side of the operator `|`), _old mac_ is `\r` (right side) and _windows_ is `\r\n`.

Comment: `| and ? are not escaped` actually inside `[]` they are not metacharacters any more (so they are escaped). Also if you want to match only one new line sequence then your first approach was correct.

Comment: You're right. So I have to replace `String lineSep = [\\r?\\n|\\r\\n?]+;` with `String lineSep = (?:\\r?\\n|\\r\\n?)+;` as you said in your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`|` in `\\r?\\n|\\r\\n?` splits your entire regex to separate parts `regex1|regex2`. To solve this problem you can put this in parenthesis. Also since you dont want to include it in your group count you can use `(?:...)` to crate non-capturing group.

So change

```
String lineSep = "\\r?\\n|\\r\\n?";
```

to

```
String lineSep = "(?:\\r?\\n|\\r\\n?)";
```

---

BTW to print content of array you should use `Arrays.toString(yourArray)` not `yourArray.toString()` so maybe change

```
System.out.println(tmp.toString())
```

to

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tmp))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're issue was in the line separator.
This worked for me from your code sample. Also the strings were not properly escaped, I had to escape the double quotes from your example.

```
final String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator").toString();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("&rule_c(2-7, <<'EOF');");
sb.append(newLine);
sb.append("cout << \"Hello World.\n\";");
sb.append(newLine);
sb.append("return x;");
sb.append(newLine);
sb.append("EOF");
sb.append(newLine);
String textual = sb.toString();

String lineSep = "(\r?\n|\r\n?)";
String regex = "\\&rule_c\\(2\\-7, <<'EOF'\\);"+lineSep+"cout << \"Hello World.\\n\";"+lineSep+"return x;"+lineSep+"EOF"+lineSep;

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(textual);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println("regex matches!");

}
else {
    System.out.println("regex doesn't match!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the "multiline" regex switch `(?m)`, which lets you use `\s` to match newlines too:

```
String regex = "(?m)^&rule_c\\((\\d+)-(\\d+),\\s?<<\\s?'EOF'\\);\\s(.*\\s)+EOF\\s$";
```

Also removed unnecessary escaping of `<`, `-` and `'`.